# Serving Laravel from a directory

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, nginx-location

I am currently using a javascript framework being served up using Nginx, for example on the following url

```
www.myjsapp.com
```

I am also using Laravel 5.6 to build an API.

Instead of building 2 hosts, one for the JS app and one for Laravel, I want to be able to serve up the Laravel API on the following URL.

```
www.jsapp.com/api
```

Is this possible or do I have to always use 2 hosts?

The nginx server block for `myjsappcom` is as follows;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .myjsapp.com;
    root "/home/project/myjsapp";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myjsapp.com-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/myjsapp.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myjsapp.com.key;
}
```

Comment: Create a reverse proxy to your nodejs in nginx, then you get both under the same domain.

Comment: @N.B. Is that done in Nginx?

Comment: Yes. in nginx. You can google for the config sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the servers using `location` blocks in your nginx config file: 
different `/location` blocks will capture different url schemes and pass them to the respective servers (node or laravel).

```
server {
    server_name mysjapp.com;

    #other configurations like root, logs

    location / {
        #node server config

    }

    location /api {
        #laravel server config
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, it makes sense, but i dont know anything about editing nginx files ... If I stick my original sites-available file for the myjsapp.com domain, would you be able to show me what you mean?

Comment: from what i know of nginx (i go through a lot of trial and error when i have to configure it myself), you should change the  
 `location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }`
 in your code with 
`location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }`
 then you would write a new `location / {}` block where you would put configuration according to node.js requirements for nginx. I have not used node myself, but i am sure you can find the configuration example somewhere on SO. Hope that helped